# updating a pgsql table using ogr2ogr, trouble with PK

Tags: postgresql, postgis, ogr2ogr

I have an issue when using ogr2ogr to import new GIS data (from osm or specific), from shp to pgsql.
To create my table, I use:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite --config PGSQL_OGR_FID myid -gt 65536 -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:host='host' user='myself' dbname=db  password='motdepasse'" -nln rues --config GDAL_DATA "C:/OSGeo4W64/share/gdal" -t_srs EPSG:2154 "C:/test01.shp"
```

With PGSQL_OGR_FID to force pgsql to use my original column as Primary key. This key will have to make possible my updating.

So, to update with new datas, I would like to do so:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append  --config PGSQL_OGR_FID myid -gt 65536 -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:host='host' user='myself' dbname=db  password='motdepasse' active_schema=public" -nln rues --config GDAL_DATA "C:/OSGeo4W64/share/gdal" -t_srs EPSG:2154 "C:/test02.shp"
```

BUT pgsql doesn't like that at all! I want it to replace data with the same PK by the new one, but it wants to keep the old one and take the new one, which is not possible of course, so the message is:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "rues_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (osm_id)=(92868916) already exists.
```

Is it possible to use ogr2ogr to replace data? It seems, when updating, wanting to keep everything...
I don't know what to do... Maybe using SQL queries in my request...

Strangely, it seems that this is working with sqlite/spatialite!
(See http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-December/031099.html)

Thanks very much if you have any solution, and sorry for my bad English!

Cyril

Comment: I don't think ogr2ogr can update a table in this way...The flag `update` only means, the datasource are open in `update` and not in `read only` mode.

Comment: OK, thank you. But, why having create an update + append mode if not to update? Very strange...

Comment: I am trying to use SQL request, especialy triggers BEFORE and AFTER when updating, but it doesn't work very nicely... If you have an idea, please, don't hesitate! Thank you!